# how we can manage multiple views in single project in DNN7

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

I'm new in DNN development.I am using DNN-7 version.actually i am running with one problem about Dnn project.
I have DNN solution with multiple projects and i want to merge all projects into single Project.
Previously, I need multiple pages so that i did multiple modules for each pages.but now it thinks too tedious job.

overall idea is that how we can manage multiple views in single project.

Answer (score 3):

The common way to do something like this is to use the `.DNN` file of your project to have multiple "packages".

You can see an example at:
https://github.com/ChrisHammond/Engage-Publish/blob/master/EngagePublish.5.dnn

```xml
<dotnetnuke version="5.0" type="Package">
  <packages>
    <package name="Engage: Publish" type="Module" version="5.7.0">
      <friendlyName>Engage: Publish</friendlyName>
      <description>The DotNetNuke Publishing module by Engage Software (www.engagesoftware.com)</description>
      <iconFile>DesktopModules/EngagePublish/Images/publish-icon32.png</iconFile>
      <owner>
        <name>Engage Software</name>
        <organization>Engage Software</organization>
        <url>http://www.engagesoftware.com/</url>
        <email>support@engagemodules.com</email>
      </owner>
      <license src="Licenses\EULA-Standard.htm" />
      <releaseNotes src="ReleaseNotes_5.7.0.htm" />
      <dependencies>
        <dependency type="CoreVersion">5.0.0</dependency>
      </dependencies>
      <components>
        <component type="ResourceFile" installOrder="0">
          <resourceFiles>
            <basePath>DesktopModules/EngagePublish</basePath>
            <resourceFile>
              <name>Resources.zip</name>
            </resourceFile>
          </resourceFiles>
        </component>
        <component type="Script" installOrder="1">
          <!-- use installOrder to guarantee that scripts run before assembly installs -->
          <!-- so that 5.7.0 script can fix incorrect assembly version numbers -->
          <scripts>
            <basePath>DesktopModules\EngagePublish</basePath>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>03.00.01.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>03.00.01</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>03.00.02.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>03.00.02</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>03.00.04.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>03.00.04</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>03.00.05.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>03.00.05</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>03.00.06.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>03.00.06</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>03.00.07.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>03.00.07</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>03.00.08.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>03.00.08</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>03.00.09.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>03.00.09</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>03.00.10.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>03.00.10</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>03.00.12.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>03.00.12</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>03.00.13.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>03.00.13</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>03.00.14.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>03.00.14</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>03.00.15.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>03.00.15</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>03.00.16.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>03.00.16</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>03.00.17.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>03.00.17</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>03.00.19.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>03.00.19</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>03.00.21.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>03.00.21</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>03.00.23.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>03.00.23</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>03.00.24.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>03.00.24</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>04.00.00.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>04.00.00</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>04.00.01.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>04.00.01</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>04.00.02.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>04.00.02</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>04.00.03.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>04.00.03</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>04.00.04.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>04.00.04</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>04.00.05.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>04.00.05</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>04.00.06.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>04.00.06</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>04.00.07.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>04.00.07</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>04.00.08.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>04.00.08</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>04.00.09.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>04.00.09</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>04.01.00.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>04.01.00</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>04.01.01.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>04.01.01</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>04.02.00.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>04.02.00</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>04.02.01.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>04.02.01</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>04.02.03.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>04.02.03</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>04.02.05.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>04.02.05</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>04.02.06.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>04.02.06</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>04.02.07.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>04.02.07</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>04.02.09.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>04.02.09</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>04.03.00.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>04.03.00</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>04.03.01.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>04.03.01</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>04.03.02.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>04.03.02</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>04.03.03.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>04.03.03</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>04.03.04.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>04.03.04</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>04.03.08.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>04.03.08</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>04.03.09.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>04.03.09</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>04.04.04.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>04.04.04</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>04.04.05.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>04.04.05</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>04.04.06.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>04.04.06</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>04.05.01.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>04.05.01</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>04.05.02.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>04.05.02</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>04.05.03.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>04.05.03</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>04.05.05.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>04.05.05</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>05.00.01.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>05.00.01</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>05.00.02.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>05.00.02</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>05.00.03.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>05.00.03</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>05.01.00.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>05.01.00</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>05.01.02.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>05.01.02</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>05.01.04.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>05.01.04</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>05.01.05.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>05.01.05</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>05.01.06.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>05.01.06</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>05.01.08.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>05.01.08</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>05.01.09.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>05.01.09</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>05.02.01.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>05.02.01</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>05.02.03.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>05.02.03</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>05.02.05.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>05.02.05</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>05.02.09.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>05.02.09</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>05.03.00.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>05.03.00</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>05.03.03.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>05.03.03</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>05.03.07.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>05.03.07</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>05.03.08.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>05.03.08</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>05.03.09.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>05.03.09</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>05.05.00.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>05.05.00</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>05.05.02.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>05.05.02</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>05.05.04.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>05.05.04</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>05.07.00.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>05.07.00</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>05.08.00.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>05.08.00</version>
            </script>
            <script type="Install">
              <name>05.08.01.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version>05.08.01</version>
            </script>
            <script type="UnInstall">
              <name>Uninstall.SqlDataProvider</name>
              <version latestVersion="latestVersion">5.7.0</version>
            </script>
          </scripts>
        </component>
        <component type="Module" installOrder="2">
          <desktopModule>
            <moduleName>Engage: Publish</moduleName>
            <foldername>EngagePublish</foldername>
            <businessControllerClass>Engage.Dnn.Publish.Util.FeaturesController</businessControllerClass>
            <supportedFeatures>
              <supportedFeature type="Portable" />
              <supportedFeature type="Searchable" />
            </supportedFeatures>
            <moduleDefinitions>
              <moduleDefinition>
                <friendlyName>Engage: Publish</friendlyName>
                <defaultCacheTime>0</defaultCacheTime>
                <moduleControls>
                  <moduleControl>
                    <controlKey></controlKey>
                    <controlSrc>DesktopModules/EngagePublish/ItemDisplay.ascx</controlSrc>
                    <controlType>View</controlType>
                    <helpUrl>http://www.EngageSoftware.com/Support.aspx</helpUrl>
                  </moduleControl>
                  <moduleControl>
                    <controlKey>AdminContainer</controlKey>
                    <controlSrc>DesktopModules/EngagePublish/AdminLoader.ascx</controlSrc>
                    <controlType>Edit</controlType>
                    <helpUrl>http://www.EngageSoftware.com/Support.aspx</helpUrl>
                  </moduleControl>
                  <moduleControl>
                    <controlKey>Settings</controlKey>
                    <controlSrc>DesktopModules/EngagePublish/ItemDisplayOptions.ascx</controlSrc>
                    <controlType>Edit</controlType>
                    <helpUrl>http://www.EngageSoftware.com/Support.aspx</helpUrl>
                  </moduleControl>
                  <moduleControl>
                    <controlKey>ItemPreview</controlKey>
                    <controlSrc>DesktopModules/EngagePublish/ItemPreview.ascx</controlSrc>
                    <controlType>Edit</controlType>
                    <helpUrl>http://www.EngageSoftware.com/Support.aspx</helpUrl>
                  </moduleControl>
                </moduleControls>
              </moduleDefinition>
            </moduleDefinitions>
          </desktopModule>
        </component>
        <component type="Assembly" installOrder="3">
          <assemblies>
            <assembly>
              <name>EngagePublish.dll</name>
              <version latestVersion="latestVersion">5.7.0</version>
            </assembly>
            <assembly>
              <name>CookComputing.XmlRpcV2.dll</name>
              <version>0.0.0</version>
            </assembly>
            <assembly>
              <name>Engage.Dnn.UserFeedback.dll</name>
              <version>1.0.1</version>
            </assembly>
            <assembly>
              <name>AjaxControlToolkit.dll</name>
              <version>1.0.20229</version>
            </assembly>
            <assembly>
              <name>Engage.Dnn.Framework.dll</name>
              <version>3.1.5</version>
            </assembly>
            <assembly>
              <name>Engage.Framework.dll</name>
              <version>3.1.3</version>
            </assembly>
          </assemblies>
        </component>
        <component type="Cleanup" installOrder="4" version="05.05.04" fileName="05.05.04.txt" />
      </components>
    </package>
    <package name="Engage: Publish Tag Cloud" type="Module" version="5.7.0">
      <friendlyName>Engage: Publish Tag Cloud</friendlyName>
      <description>The tag cloud for the Engage: Publish module.</description>
      <iconFile>DesktopModules/EngagePublish/Images/publish-icon32.png</iconFile>
      <owner>
        <name>Engage Software</name>
        <organization>Engage Software</organization>
        <url>http://www.engagesoftware.com/</url>
        <email>support@engagemodules.com</email>
      </owner>
      <license src="Licenses\EULA-Standard.htm" />
      <releaseNotes src="ReleaseNotes_5.7.0.htm" />
      <components>
        <component type="Module">
          <desktopModule>
            <moduleName>Engage: Publish Tag Cloud</moduleName>
            <foldername>EngagePublish/Tags</foldername>
            <businessControllerClass>Engage.Dnn.Publish.Util.FeaturesController</businessControllerClass>
            <supportedFeatures>
              <supportedFeature type="Portable" />
              <supportedFeature type="Searchable" />
            </supportedFeatures>
            <moduleDefinitions>
              <moduleDefinition>
                <friendlyName>Engage: Publish Tag Cloud</friendlyName>
                <defaultCacheTime>0</defaultCacheTime>
                <moduleControls>
                  <moduleControl>
                    <controlKey></controlKey>
                    <controlSrc>DesktopModules/EngagePublish/Tags/TagCloud.ascx</controlSrc>
                    <controlType>View</controlType>
                    <helpUrl>http://EngageSoftware.com/Support.aspx</helpUrl>
                  </moduleControl>
                  <moduleControl>
                    <controlKey>Settings</controlKey>
                    <controlSrc>DesktopModules/EngagePublish/Tags/TagCloudOptions.ascx</controlSrc>
                    <controlType>Edit</controlType>
                    <helpUrl>http://EngageSoftware.com/Support.aspx</helpUrl>
                  </moduleControl>
                </moduleControls>
              </moduleDefinition>
            </moduleDefinitions>
          </desktopModule>
        </component>
      </components>
    </package>
    <package name="Engage: Publish Text/HTML" type="Module" version="5.7.0">
      <friendlyName>Engage: Text/HTML</friendlyName>
      <description>A Text/HTML replacement module for the Engage: Publish workflow system.</description>
      <iconFile>DesktopModules/EngagePublish/Images/publish-icon32.png</iconFile>
      <owner>
        <name>Engage Software</name>
        <organization>Engage Software</organization>
        <url>http://www.engagesoftware.com/</url>
        <email>support@engagemodules.com</email>
      </owner>
      <license src="Licenses\EULA-Standard.htm" />
      <releaseNotes src="ReleaseNotes_5.7.0.htm" />
      <components>
        <component type="Module">
          <desktopModule>
            <moduleName>Engage: Publish Text/HTML</moduleName>
            <foldername>EngagePublish/TextHTML</foldername>
            <businessControllerClass>Engage.Dnn.Publish.TextHTML.FeaturesController</businessControllerClass>
            <supportedFeatures>
              <supportedFeature type="Portable" />
              <supportedFeature type="Searchable" />
            </supportedFeatures>
            <moduleDefinitions>
              <moduleDefinition>
                <friendlyName>Engage: Publish Text/HTML</friendlyName>
                <defaultCacheTime>0</defaultCacheTime>
                <moduleControls>
                  <moduleControl>
                    <controlKey></controlKey>
                    <controlSrc>DesktopModules/EngagePublish/TextHTML/View.ascx</controlSrc>
                    <controlType>View</controlType>
                    <helpUrl>http://EngageSoftware.com/Support.aspx</helpUrl>
                  </moduleControl>
                  <moduleControl>
                    <controlKey>Edit</controlKey>
                    <controlSrc>DesktopModules/EngagePublish/TextHTML/Edit.ascx</controlSrc>
                    <controlType>Edit</controlType>
                    <helpUrl>http://EngageSoftware.com/Support.aspx</helpUrl>
                  </moduleControl>
                  <moduleControl>
                    <controlKey>AdminContainer</controlKey>
                    <controlSrc>DesktopModules/EngagePublish/AdminLoader.ascx</controlSrc>
                    <controlType>Edit</controlType>
                    <helpUrl>http://EngageSoftware.com/Support.aspx</helpUrl>
                  </moduleControl>
                </moduleControls>
              </moduleDefinition>
            </moduleDefinitions>
          </desktopModule>
        </component>
      </components>
    </package>
  </packages>
</dotnetnuke>
```

Comment: its working...thanks !!! but on DNN site it showing multiple modules...can't we do like it shows only one module?

Comment: yes, if you want to have a single Module in the Add Module list, yet have to load up more than one module on a page, like the DNN Blog module does, you can modify the Manifest to duplicate the 
              <moduleDefinition>              </moduleDefinition>
Section inside of               <moduleDefinitions>, instead of duplicating the Packages option like my example above does.